# How to export Angular 10 guard using DOCUMENT for public-api

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

I have an Angular 10 library that has a guard. I want to export the guard to use on the consuming application's router. I went the path of exporting the guard in my `public-api.ts` but I get a build error that `Document` type cannot be resolved. I'm injecting `DOCUMENT` into my guard. Error and guard code below. Any advice for exporting?

**Build error:**

```
Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Could not resolve type Document.
  {"__symbolic":"error","message":"Could not resolve type","line":19,"character":40,"context":{"typeName":"Document"}}
```

**Guard:**

```
import { Inject, Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { QrRedirectService } from './qr-redirect.service';
import { MobileOS, QrUser } from '../qr-lib.model';
import { QR_LIB_CONFIG } from '../qr-lib.config.token';
import { QrLibConfig } from '../qr-lib.config';
@Injectable()
export class QrRedirectGuard implements CanActivate, OnDestroy {
  config: QrLibConfig;
  qrUser: QrUser;
  redirectUrl: string;
  redirectSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(
    @Inject(QR_LIB_CONFIG) qrLibConfig,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    public qrRedirectService: QrRedirectService,
    public router: Router,
  ) {
    if (qrLibConfig) {
      this.config = qrLibConfig;
    }
    (this.redirectSubscription = this.qrRedirectService
      .getQrUser()
      .subscribe((user: QrUser) => {
        this.qrUser = user;
      })),
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-unused-expression
      (error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
      };
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.redirectSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  /**
   * The `Window` object from `Document` defaultView.
   */
  get window(): Window {
    return this.document.defaultView || window;
  }
  /**
   * Redirects instantly to the external link without the mediation of the router.
   */
  public redirect(url: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        resolve(!!this.window.open(url));
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  }
  /**
   * Returns `true` if user is on Android device.
   */
  isAndroid(osName: string): boolean {
    return osName === MobileOS.Android;
  }
  /**
   * Returns `true` if user is on iOS device.
   */
  isIOS(osName: string): boolean {
    return osName === MobileOS.iOS;
  }
  /**
   * Returns `false` if `QrUser` and `os` are valid, redirects to app store,
   * and directs the router to stop navigation.
   * Returns `true` if `QrUser` or `os` is invalid which directs the router
   * to continue with navigation.
   */
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.qrUser && this.qrUser.os) {
      if (this.isAndroid(this.qrUser.os)) {
        this.redirectUrl = this.config.androidStoreUrl;
      }
      if (this.isIOS(this.qrUser.os)) {
        this.redirectUrl = this.config.iosStoreUrl;
      }
      if (this.redirectUrl) {
        // Jumps to the external url
        this.redirect(this.redirectUrl).then(() => false);
      }
    }
    // default route (qr landing page)
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document` to `@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any` should allow your lib to build.

Comment: Experienced the same 2 weeks ago. Building further on this, you can still remove the `private` keyword from the injection parameter (`@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: any`), add a `private document: Document;` field to your class, and make the assignment in the constructor (`this.document = <Document>document;`). This way you don't have to do the cast every time you want to use the `document`. As long as the injection parameter is of type `any`.